# How much time do I have after drop out to come back to my country?

Tags: united-states, university, international-students, visa

I am a full funded international student of PhD grade in US. I like to know if I drop out the study, how much time do I have to stay in US before come back to my country?

Comment: I think this question is off-topic here. You should talk to your university's international office. Generally, students in the US on an F-1 visa have a 60-day grace period to leave the country after completing their program, but only 15 days if they withdraw. See e.g. https://www.gallaudet.edu/office-of-international-affairs/international-student-and-scholar-services/f-1-status-information/f-1-grace-periods

Comment: @Thomas Seems on-topic to me, it has to do with a problem academics (and only academics face). We have a [visa] tag, after all. You even just posted the answer

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim This seems more appropriate for https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ It's also a question that can be answered with 2 minutes of googling.

Comment: @Thomas Being on-topic at Expatriates has no bearing on whether it's on topic here. I don't think we have a rule on how easy an answer is to find, unlike some sites that have a "no research" reason.